# how do I install this php word censor for phpBB?

Tags: php, phpbb, phpbb3

I am trying to add a list of words to be censored.

So I found this site

http://www.phpbbsmith.com/projects/phpbb3/word-censor-list.html

that does it for phpBB. I downloaded the file and I put it in my root folder.

I get this error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function session_begin() on a non-object in C:\HostingSpaces\SomeName\Site.com\wwwroot\Forum\install.php on line 18
```

I am not sure what really is happening I don't use php. My current structure is I have an asp.net mvc application that sites in the root. I then made a virtual directory called Forum that holds phpBB and this is where I stuck the install.php file in the root of this virtual directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't* run PHP code in a ASP.NET MVC application. You will have to find a component that is written for ASP.NET MVC.

*Well... you can, but it's probably not what you want to do: http://www.php-compiler.net/doku.php

Comment: Correct you can't run php code in an asp.net MVC application. Hence why I made a virtual directory that has php enabled(my hosting provides both .net hosting and php hosting with all plans). I am running the message board as we speak. So its not like it is working. It's just this install script that I am trying to run in my virtual directory is not working.

Comment: So the virtual directory has PHP but the root (where you put this file) doesn't.  I'm not sure why the script says it needs to be in your root folder, but you'll have to put it somewhere that can deal with PHP.

Comment: Nono I put the file in the root of the virtual directory. So it is in the virtual directory.

Answer (score 0):

root/ in this context (a phpBB mod install) means the root directory of a working phpBB install. Not your server document root.